# Filtering dates for pivot table data based on cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to filter pivot tables in a sheet based on two different dates in two different cells (basically dynamic cells where someone can enter the start date) and the pivot would refresh based on those dates. I don't have much experience with VBA and all the codes that I've found online doesn't really work.

Sheet 1
6 pivot tables
2 dates (date a in cell F2 and date b in cell F3)

3 pivot tables filter according to date a
3 pivot filter filter according to date b

can someone help me with this!